# Photoswipe.js toolbar hidden

Tags: jquery, photoswipe

(first of all, we didn't want the site to look this way, it was the client's choice)

I'm using Photoswipe.js(http://www.photoswipe.com/) for the thumbnails below, but the toolbar isn't showing up.
http://dev.realtyvictoria.com/listings/listing-details/307911

Photoswipe.js is loading, photoswipe.css is loading, klass.min.js is loading, and I can see the images under Chrome's Developer Tools > resources.

I've tried using ../images and /images in photoswipe.css

I'm already using "captionAndToolbarAutoHideDelay: 0, captionAndToolbarHide: false"...

But still no toolbar.  Any help?

Thanks

Comment: nevermind, I think I just need to update the Jquery version.

Comment: yep, that was it.  was using jquery 1.4.3 - it needed the latest version.